# How to count words in Javascript, and cut off when reaching X

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my current code which cuts off the text at 150 chars.

```
"<p class='review-text'>" + reviews[i].text.substr(0, 150) + "read more" + "</p>"
```

Is there a simple method of doing this with X amount of words?

(New to Javascript, I apologize).

Comment: `string.split(" ").slice(0, x)`

Comment: @destoryer might be better to use `.split(/\s+/)` to catch other whitespace characters and repetition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/split) the string and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the resulting array:

```
var limit = 20; #limit to 20 words
reviews[i].text.split(" ", limit).join(" ");
```

If there are multiple spaces between words in the string you could use a `regex` to `split`:

```
reviews[i].text.split(/\s+/, limit).join(" ");
```

Comment: Same comment as above, `.split(/\s+/, limit)` might be a better option to account for other whitespace characters and repetition

Comment: I linked instead to MDN, which is a more reliable resource than w3schools.

Comment: Gotcha, noticed that after the comment ;)

Comment: I love this forum. Thank you @ShawnNorthrop, works a treat. For some reason, it has broke my the page a little. Have I formatted it correctly? `"<div class='review-item border mt-3' style='background-color:white;'><div class='review-meta'><span class='review-author'>"+reviews[i].author_name+"</span><span class='review-sep'> </span></div>"+stars+"<hr><p class='review-text'>" + reviews[i].text.split(/\s+/, limit).join(" "); + "</p></div>"`

Comment: remove the `;` after the join